# Cakephp 3 Jsonview and AdminLTE

Tags: json, ajax, request, cakephp-3.x, adminlte

I am using the current Cakephp 3.6.3 and via composer additional

```
composer require maiconpinto/cakephp-adminlte-theme
```

In the tutorial of Maicon Pinto it is described how to set up the controllers and views. All is fine so far.
Now I'm trying to use json via ajax from my site. 
All extensions in route.php are done as stated in
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

In the controller I'm using

```
$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

is included.

The issue I have now is, that always a MissingTemplateException is thrown:

```
Error: The view for NameController::action() was not found.
```

Here a part of the debug site's output:

```
response => object(Cake\Http\Response) {

    'status' => (int) 200,
    'contentType' => 'application/json',
    'headers' => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ],
    'file' => null,
    'fileRange' => [[maximum depth reached]],
    'cookies' => object(Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection) {},
    'cacheDirectives' => [[maximum depth reached]],
    'body' => ''

}
paginate => []
components => []
View => object(AdminLTE\View\AdminLTEView) {
    Blocks => object(Cake\View\ViewBlock) {}
    plugin => null
    name => '<Modelname>'
    passedArgs => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ]
    helpers => [[maximum depth reached]]
    templatePath => '<Modelname>'
    template => 'fill'
    layout => 'default'
    layoutPath => null
    autoLayout => true
    subDir => null
    theme => 'AdminLTE'
    hasRendered => false
    uuids => [[maximum depth reached]]
    request => object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest) {}
    response => object(Cake\Http\Response) {}
    elementCache => 'default'
    viewClass => null
    viewVars => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ]
    Form => object(AdminLTE\View\Helper\FormHelper) {}
    [protected] _helpers => object(Cake\View\HelperRegistry) {}
    [protected] _ext => '.ctp'
    [protected] _passedVars => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ]
    [protected] _paths => [
        [maximum depth reached]
    ]
    [protected] _pathsForPlugin => [[maximum depth reached]]
    [protected] _parents => [[maximum depth reached]]
    [protected] _current => null
    [protected] _currentType => ''
    [protected] _stack => [[maximum depth reached]]
    [protected] _viewBlockClass => 'Cake\View\ViewBlock'
    [protected] _eventManager => object(Cake\Event\EventManager) {}
    [protected] _eventClass => 'Cake\Event\Event'
    [protected] _viewBuilder => null
}
```

So what is missing, that Cakephp is not requesting a template but using the normal JsonView as foreseen in the documentation? It looks, as the framework has correctly detected the JSON data and wants also to send out a JSON response. I also tried to set the viewBuilder in my action to

```
$this->viewBuilder('Json');
```

without any success.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by changing the classname in beforeRender:

```
public function beforeRender(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
    parent::beforeRender($event);
    if ($this->getRequest()->is('ajax') || $this->getRequest()->is('json')){
        $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('Json');
    }
}
```

Now I get the right format.